# How do I detect Workbox.register precache request failure?

Tags: workbox

I register my serviceworker through Workbox with

```
        const wb = new Workbox("/sw.js");

        wb.register();
```

This works great, and installs no problems. ( I am using workbox-precaching, and SWInjectManifest built through webpack )

My problem comes when I deliberately force one of the requests in my precaching manifest to fail, which I do by deleting one built file.

Workbox dev logging tells me

```
Service worker installation failed. It will be retried automatically during the next navigation.

Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: The precaching request for 'http://localhost:8080/GalanoGrotesqueAlt-Regular.woff' failed with an HTTP status of 404.
```

Ideally I'd like to let the user retry. I build apps that are used in low quality network environments, so detecting these errors can be quite important.

I have tried:

1. wrapping `wb.register()` in a try catch ( it does not raise an exception )
2. chaining a `.catch()` off `wb.register()` ( it does not return a promise )
3. listening to non-existent 'error' events on Workbox ( they don't exist )
4. wrapping the call to `precacheAndRoute` in the service worker ( it does not raise an exception )
5. listening to 'error' events on the ServiceWorkerController ( which is [unsupported](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/912) )
6. setting self.onerror, and listening to self `error` events in the serviceworker code ( they do not fire )

https://plnkr.co/edit/jymNXaeLvsZU1OJx?preview

My two options now are:

1. try to use webpack alias to override the workbox logger code
2. just offer a retry button after a guestimated time

I love the plugins workbox gives me, but the abstraction is beginning to hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario you describe, where there's an error thrown while performing precaching, registration is successful, but the installation process fails.

When that happens, the `ServiceWorker` object associated with the registration will transition from the `installing` state to the terminal error state, which is `redundant`.

You can detect this failure using `workbox-window` by listening for the [`redundant` state change](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-window.Workbox#event:redundant) event:

```
wb.addEventListener('redundant', (event) => {
  // Handle installation failure here.
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I don't know how I missed that event while trying all the others :)